How to plot a simple line with mayavi?
Apparently, I do not understand how to plot a simple line with mayavi. According to the docs, I should use mlab.plot3d, where the first three arguments x, y, z contain the coordinates:

x, y, z and s are numpy arrays or lists of the same shape. x, y and z give the positions of the successive points of the line

[quoted from the docs, see the previous link]
So I thought I should give this a try and wrote the following piece of code:
import numpy as np
from mayavi import mlab

fig1 = mlab.figure( bgcolor=(1,1,1), fgcolor=(0,0,0))

myLine = mlab.plot3d( np.array( [2, 3, 4] ),    # x
                      np.array( [1, 1, 1] ),    # y
                      np.array( [1, 1, 1] ),    # z
                      representation='points',
                      line_width=1,
                    )

ax1 = mlab.axes( color=(0,0,0), 
                 nb_labels=4,
                 extent=[0, 5,
                         0, 2,
                         0, 2, ],
               )

mlab.outline(ax1)
mlab.show()

Unfortunately, this does not result in a line, but in a cuboid: 
Looking at the image, also the starting coordinates are not what I set in the code: I thought it should start at (2,1,1), corresponding to the first value of each of the arrays.
Summarizing, I seem not to understand how to use plot3d. What am I missing?

in other questions I saw suggestion that it has to be represented as tube: plot - How to draw a line in Python Mayavi? - Stack Overflow Maybe like in mathematics - line does't have thickness - so it has to draw tube to show it. And when you draw small line then you see that it is tube (or other figure) which simulate line.

documentation in your link suggests to use tube_radius=None : tube_radius: radius of the tubes used to represent the lines, If None, simple lines are used

Documentation in your link suggests to use tube_radius=None

tube_radius: radius of the tubes used to represent the lines, If None, simple lines are used

In axes I used nb_labels=5, and [1,5] instead of [0, 5] so it better shows size of line.
import numpy as np
from mayavi import mlab

fig1 = mlab.figure(bgcolor=(1,1,1), fgcolor=(0,0,0))

myLine = mlab.plot3d( np.array( [2, 3, 4] ),    # x
                      np.array( [1, 1, 1] ),    # y
                      np.array( [1, 1, 1] ),    # z
                      representation='points',
                      line_width=1,
                      tube_radius=None  # <----
                    )

ax1 = mlab.axes( color=(0,0,0), 
                 nb_labels=5,
                 extent=[1, 5,
                         0, 1,
                         0, 1, ],
               )

mlab.outline(ax1)
mlab.show()



Other example (without mlab.outline(ax1) which may hide line):
import numpy as np
from mayavi import mlab

fig1 = mlab.figure(bgcolor=(1,1,1), fgcolor=(0,0,0))

myLine = mlab.plot3d( np.array( [2, 4, 4, 2,  2,  3] ),    # x
                      np.array( [1, 1, 0, 0, .5, .5] ),    # y
                      np.array( [1, 1, 1, 1,  1,  1] ),    # z
                      #representation='points',
                      #line_width=1,
                      tube_radius=None,
                      #tube_radius=0.01,
                    )

ax1 = mlab.axes( color=(0,0,0), 
                 nb_labels=5,
                 extent=[1, 5,
                         0, 1,
                         0, 1, ],
               )

#mlab.outline(ax1)
mlab.show()



Indeed, that works, thanks! Interestingly, what also works is if I simply use floating point values in my example above as coordinates and not integers. Not sure if that is intended or rather a small bug...?
